# Client-Side API for TFS / MTM TestRunner?

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

Does anyone know for a fact whether or not the microsoft test manager for tfs 2010 throws any client side events like OnFinished/OnSaved etc? I am asking because our business process requires certain minimum amount of information in each test run/result to be provided prior to closing the testrun (e.g. in case of a failed step a reason and or defect id has to be provided at the affected steps' comment field).

Postprocessing / report-driven checks etc makes basically means the tester *can* make 'errors' and we'll have to re-test the whole tc instead of having a prompt process check which allows fixing the tc immediately..

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, by developing a [Custom Diagnostic Data Adapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286737.aspx) you could implement this.
Using perhaps the TestCaseEnd event, you can get to the TestElement via the [TestCaseEndEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.execution.testcaseendeventargs.aspx) and do your processing.